# Why don't we have processors with 64 bit address lines and 128 bit registers?

Tags: operating-system, processor

So I was just reading about 8086 processors and found out all the addressing issues they faced due to 20bit addressing lines and 16 bit data registers.

Now that we have 64 bit address lines which can access upto 2^64 bytes of RAM why don't we have 128bit data registers? Won't it be much more efficient?

Comment: x86 has had 128bit registers available since Pentium III as part of SSE. They're not general purpose, but seem to be the type we need.

Comment: so are you saying that all current processors have 128 bit data registers?

Comment: Certainly not all current processors out there. But pretty much all current x86 processors have 128bit registers, many 256bit and some of the newest even 512bit registers.

Comment: At the moment, x86 doesn't even have 64 bit addressing. It can currently only do 48 bits of physical addressing (this is a limitation imposed by the structure of the page tables). Technically, logical addresses (commonly known as virtual addresses) could use, I believe,  52 bits in the future without major changes to the spec, but they are converted down 48 bit physical addresses.